Disabling specific compiler option with intel ifort compiler
In order to debug some code, I'm trying to use the "-check pointers" option. But it warn me and stop the run on some specific cases that I know are unrelated and non-problematic.
I am then wondering if there exists a directive to add directly in the source files to disable the option for those specific files.
I'm looking for something similar to the directive "!DEC$ NOOPTIMIZE" but more general, so I could choose which option to disable.
Also I cannot activate or deactivate the option for a specific file with the build system, because we are using an in-house and complicated system.

This does not directly answer the question, but can't you modify the "unrelated and non-problematic cases" so that they don't trigger an error?

Seconded. You've found a bug. You can't tell for absolute 100% certain it is unconnected to the "problematic case", once something goes wrong anything can go wrong. Fix what you have found and then move onto the next problem.

To elaborate more, there are 2 possibilities.... Unlikely (but possible): a false positive from ifort; More likely: some illegal code encountered. Even if you think the (possibly) illegal code is harmless, the best shot is to fix it. Unless you really know what you're doing...
